# Font Awesome only displaying ASCII characters on xamarin

Tags: xamarin, fonts, font-awesome

**TL;DR**

Font Awesome 5 Solid is only showing ASCII characters in my xamarin app but not special font awesome characters.

**My Situation:**

I have added the [Font Awesome 5 Solid](https://fontawesome.com/icons/?s=solid) font to my xamarin project to make use of [the cannabis icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/cannabis)

These are the steps I took to add the font:

1. Adding the .otf file to the Android `Assets` folder
2. Defining a name for the font for each platform in my App.xaml like so:

   ```
   <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">
        <On Platform="Android" 
            Value="FontAwesome5Solid.otf" />
        <On Platform="iOS" 
            Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" />
        <On Platform="UWP" 
            Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Solid.otf" />
   </OnPlatform>
   ```

Then I try to access the font within a `xaml` `<span>` like so:

`<Span Text="&#xf55f;"FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" />`

For reference, see the entire code chunk below.

```
  <Label.FormattedText>
       <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="&#xf55f;"FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" />
            <Span Text="{Binding Source={x:Static model:User.Rating}, StringFormat='{0}'}"
                  Style="{StaticResource MenuLabel}">
                  <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                       <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" />
                  </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
       </FormattedString>
  </Label.FormattedText>
```

**The Problem:**

Normal ASCII letters such as `A-Z 0-9` work fine, when I access them using the HTML entities code and special ASCII characters like `Å` even work. If I use `Text="&#x49;"`, this results in the label having the letter `1` as its text, as expected.

The Cannabis symbol for Font Awesome 5 Solid is `f55f`, but when I include `Text="#xf55f;"` in my label, I get the little box with the cross (character not found error).

Comment: Your .otf file BuildAction marked AndriodAsset?

Answer (score 0):

How about change App.xaml like this:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
            x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid"> 
  <On Platform="Android" 
      Value="FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Regular" /> 
  <On Platform="iOS" 
      Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" /> 
  <On Platform="UWP" 
      Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" /> 
</OnPlatform>
```

reference: https://medium.com/@tsjdevapps/use-fontawesome-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2edf25311db4